# Which part of Jain philosophy suggests Jains to follow very strict austerities or penance (Tapa)?

Tags: jainism

Which part of Jain philosophy suggests Jains to follow very strict austerities or penance (Tapa)? Answer using exact reference from the original Jain scriptures. What is the philosophical logic and reasoning behind punishing the body?

Comment: This question isn't really relevant to this site. So, it would be better to delete it.

Comment: Instead of just commenting, use your privilege to cast close vote.@Bingming